# How to use Eigen with long double?

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to call the sparse linear system solvers of the Eigen package in my C++ program. However, I don't know how to use these solvers if my matrix and vector are of type `long double`. Could you please help me with rewriting the sample code (arising from the home page of Eigen) below so that it can handle long double matrices and vectors?

```
#include <Eigen/RequiredModuleName>
// ...
SparseMatrix<double> A;
// fill A
VectorXd b, x;
// fill b
// solve Ax = b
SolverClassName<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
solver.compute(A);
if(solver.info()!=Success) {
  // decomposition failed
  return;
}
x = solver.solve(b);
if(solver.info()!=Success) {
  // solving failed
  return;
}
// solve for another right hand side:
x1 = solver.solve(b1);
```

Comment: How far does replacing "double" with "long double" get you? Also are doubles and long doubles different on your platform? If they are the same it would make things a lot easier. [Does sizeof(double) == sizeof(long double) ?]

Comment: Note that some third-party solvers will not work for `long double`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the the `Eigen` datatypes, including vectors and matrices, are templates exactly for this reason.

All you should do is to replace `double` in the template parameter from your snippet with `long double` and it should work (assuming this is what you are after):

```
// ...
SparseMatrix<long double> A;
// fill A
VectorXd b, x;
// fill b
// solve Ax = b
SolverClassName<SparseMatrix<long double> > solver;
solver.compute(A);
if(solver.info()!=Success) {
  // decomposition failed
  return;
}
// ...
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. By the way, what is the situation with VectorXd?

Comment: VectorXd is a typedef of Matrix (typedefs are a way to add new types based on other types - here it is used to make code less verbose and more readable), with double elements, Dynamic (i.e. variable) number of rows and one column: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga8554c6170729f01c7572574837ecf618